# AJAX Get Request Button

Tags: javascript, ajax, button, get, xmlhttprequest

I want when I click the button a GET Request to send but I don't know how to connect the AJAX script with the button.

```js
<script>
var url = "http://myurl.com";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }};

xhr.send();
</script>
```

```html
<head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<button>Make a request</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need transform it in a function and call by the button:

```
<script>
    function call()
    {
        var url = "http://myurl.com";
        
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url);
        
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
           if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
              console.log(xhr.status);
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
           }};
        
        xhr.send();     
    }
    </script>

<head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<button onclick="call();">Make a request</button>
```

Comment: (index):1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myurl' from origin 'http://ip' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
(index):22 GETmyurl::ERR_FAILED

Comment: This is because myurl.com is not in the same domain as the call. You must make a call to the same domain or enable cross on the server receiving the call.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are importing Jquery, there is also a helper function to fetch data from an AJAX request, you can use it like this:

```
<head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<button>Make a request</button>
<!-- Javascript -->
<script>
$('button').click(function(){
    $.get("http://myurl.com", function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});

</script>
```